# Getting first condition of GROUP BY as additional rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sql string as below;

```
SELECT
            Country,
            City,
            COUNT(*) AS [Count]
        FROM
            CountiresAndCities
        GROUP BY
            Country, 
            City
```

I would like to get Countries value too as additional rows without using UNION is it possible?

Thank you in adavance.

Comment: What do you mean by Countries value? Like COUNT(Country)?

Comment: this string doesn't return country and its total count without UNION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this

```
SELECT Country,
       City,
       COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM   CountiresAndCities
GROUP  BY grouping sets ( ( Country, City ), ( Country ) )
ORDER  BY grouping(City),
          Country,
          City
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd1e8/1)

Comment: Can I use HAVING for any grouping with this appoach?

Comment: Yes. Depending on what you are trying to do you might need the `grouping` function. Random Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd1e8/3/0

Comment: Thank you very much. But I am new for this approach and I can't understand clearly. How can I do if COUNTRY CITY count > 1 then get additional COUNTRY row?

Comment: @Kerberos can you ask a new question with example data and desired results for that data?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I came up with is to use a sub-query to calculate the country-sum:

Example (using SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE Games ( Country TEXT, City TEXT );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'USA', 'New York' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'USA', 'New York' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'USA', 'New York' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'USA', 'Los Angeles' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'USA', 'Los Angeles' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'USA', 'San Francisco' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'USA', 'San Francisco' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'France', 'Paris' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'France', 'Paris' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'France', 'Paris' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'France', 'Paris' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'Spain', 'Madrid' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'Spain', 'Madrid' );
INSERT INTO Games VALUES ( 'Spain', 'Barcelona' );
.headers on
.mode column
SELECT Country, City, MIN(CountryCount) AS CountryCount, COUNT(*) AS CityCount
FROM CountiresAndCities JOIN (
    SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS CountryCount
    FROM CountiresAndCities GROUP BY Country
  ) USING (Country)
GROUP BY Country, City;

Country     City        CountryCount  CityCount 
----------  ----------  ------------  ----------
France      Paris       4             4         
Spain       Barcelona   3             1         
Spain       Madrid      3             2         
USA         Los Angele  7             2         
USA         New York    7             3         
USA         San Franci  7             2
```